# How to efficiently get latest Insert Time Stamp on a table with millions of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, triggers, sql-server-2016, sql-view

I have a question regarding table design / query efficiency in SQL.

I have two tables, Table A contains list of clients, Table B contains clients ID and the last time a message has been received from a client.

The number of clients is growing and in tens of 1000, each client sends a message at least once a minute, sometimes more, sometimes less, but on average it is about that.

Table B is growing rather fast.

The question is this: I want to be able to pull a list of all clients and their last seen date and time.

The problem is as the table grows the query execution time is getting larger and requires scan of all of the rows in Table A and B.

I have introduced a new column to Table B which is just a date type column and created non clustered, non-unique an index on it, however it does not seem to make much difference.

The query is:

```
SELECT [TableA].[Client_ID] ISNULL(R.Most_Recent_TimeStamp, '2000-01-01') AS Most_Recent_Comms
FROM [TableA]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [TableB].[Client_ID], MAX([TableB].[Time_Stamp]) AS Most_Recent_TimeStamp FROM [TableB] WITH(NOLOCK) GROUP BY [TableB].[Client_ID]) AS R ON [TableA].[Client_ID] = R.Client_ID
```

The execution time is in tens of seconds. Things have improved when I included WITH(NOLOCK) statement a fair amount. And you can imagine as the time progresses and TableB grows, execution time will be growing.

I do not think this is the right way to go.

I am sure there is a better way. What about creating a view or another table and writing a trigger, which will update the new table every time a row is inserted in to TableB. The new table will be always kept up to date and one can call simple SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of the following:

```
SELECT b.ClientId, MAX(b.TimeStamp)
FROM TableB b
GROUP BY b.ClientId;
```

This assumes that all clients are in `TableB`.  If not:

```
SELECT a.ClientId, b.TimeStamp
FROM TableA OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT b.*
      FROM TableB b
      WHERE b.Client_Id = a.Client_Id
      ORDER BY b.TimeStamp DESC
     ) b;
```

For both queries, you want an index on `TableB(ClientId, TimeStamp)`.